# Horrible lawn over compacted canal drainage

Tags: lawn

Moved into Del home a year ago and lawn looks horrible. Much is dead and unable to penetrate the compacted 12”+ of de-watered canal drainage. Have kept up with using the irrigation system as instructed. Applied pelletized lime and peat. No change after two weeks. Some sod pulls up easily.

Comment: Two ideas: Expand your garden by shrinking bad-lawn acreage. Lime adds alkaline and peat adds acid, so which do you want?

Comment: pictures would help us give you a better answer

Comment: And a clear question, please. We kind of guess that your *intend* to ask something like “how can I make my lawn look good again”, but there’s a bunch of other potential questions, e.g. what are alternatives to grass.